# Fifa career and stadium capacity

Tags: fifa-18

I am starting a new manager career with Valencia in FIFA 18. Since their stadium is not in the game, I have an option to select a stadium. Question, does the capacity of the stadium selected somehow affect the numbers in the financial aspect of career mode?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've experienced the stadium will not affect your budget directly as ticket sales do not count towards your budget.

It is useful for ticket sales and its value in general to increase your club's worth, but the budget still depends on other factors... mainly your squad, transfers and objectives.

It does *not* affect your goals like "*achieve x attendance in y matches*" or increasing your season ticket holders. That's something you can do with your club's performance.